# Unable to read the last duplicate key of a Properties file

Tags: java, properties, resourcebundle

I am trying to read the last value corresponding to a duplicate key in my *mail.properties* file. The properties file body looks like :

```
//other key/values properties
mail.body=body1

mail.subject=Reminder
mail.body=body2

mail.body=body3
//other key/values properties
```

The *mail.properties* is a result of the concatenation of many properties files at build time. The present evolution requires that I read the last `mail.subject` and `mail.body` key/value entries. Thus the normal behavior of my `resourceBundle.getString("mail.body")` should return *body3* but it returns *body2* instead. I have double checked if I am reading the right file and it seems that everything is correct. What could be the reason behind this abnormal behavior ?

Comment: Is it not finding it because you don't have a new line at the end of your file?

Comment: I checked that too. The carriage return is there and there are other properties beneath which are also read.

Comment: I have even printed the content of META-INF/mail.properties in the console. There are three 'mail.body' duplicate entries and the one being returned by the ResourceBundle object is the second entry not the last one (i.e. the third).

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Same question has repeated by you. Could you please remove either one question add all the information together ?